# How to punctuate a sentence ending in a code block on Stack Exchange

Tags: grammar, punctuation, periods

A lot of time when I'm writing a [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenge, I need to incorporate multiline blocks of code

```
like
this
```

into my sentences.

Many times, it's simplest to have them at the very end of a sentence. For example, this scenario is easy to envision:

> If the input is 1, the output of your program should be
>
> ```
> sample output 1
> ```
>
> If the input is 2, the output of your program should be
>
> ```
> sample output 2
> ```

The problem is that there are supposed to be two complete sentences here, but there are no periods!

One obvious solution is to add periods after the code blocks:

> If the input is 1, the output of your program should be
>
> ```
> sample output 1
> ```
>
> . If the input is 2, the output of your program should be
>
> ```
> sample output 2
> ```
>
> .

But this just looks weird.

Another solution is to add 'this:' after the 'be', and forgo the periods:

> If the input is 1, the output of your program should be this:
>
> ```
> sample output 1
> ```
>
> If the input is 2, the output of your program should be this:
>
> ```
> sample output 2
> ```

(I don't think it's grammatically correct to just put the colon after 'be' but I may be wrong.)

This seems more complete, but is still rather awkward with the 'this'es, and won't always work if the sentence is more complex. e.g.

> The program
>
> ```
> example code A
> ```
>
> runs better than
>
> ```
> example code B
> ```
>
> [comma?] but both are worse than
>
> ```
> example code C
> ```
>
> [period?]

So what's the best way to do this - specifically on Stack Exchange where it's impossible to put a period directly after a code block?

Comment: Maybe more relevant on some meta site? Idk, I like your stuff on PPCG though :) EDIT: I personally like *If the input is 1, the output of your program should be:*

Comment: Just do the best you can, given the tools you have.  If you ever publish a book, the editors will likely have some style suggestions to address the issue.

Comment: @HotLicks http://achewood.com/index.php?date=07102002

Comment: Understand that the "rules" for punctuating sentences were developed before there was an Internet, and, for that matter, before there were computers.  At best there were rules for embedding "block quotes" in your text, but these were not anticipating the need to embed code segments.  In another 50 years perhaps a "standard" scheme will be worked out (but of course by then it will be irrelevant, as the issue will become embedding thought waves or some such).

Comment: And far more important than adhering to some rules is producing a result that conveys your intend and that your reader will be able to understand, without too many Ouija consultations.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, if you will, a hypothetical Manners SE site, where someone posts:

If the person you're talking to gets mad, your response should be

```
don't get mad!
```

But if they seem happy, your response should be

```
I'm glad you're happy!
```

This works because it's a more clear way of formatting

> But if they seem happy, your response should be, "I'm glad you're happy!"

This sentence, in turn, is valid because the exclamation point within the quote also counts for the main sentence (I think?).

By analogy, a block of code's natural termination point, in this scenario, not only signals the end of the code block, but of the sentence containing the code block.

This is my theory. In the absence of a Stack Exchange style guide, it should be open to the individual's reasonable taste.

Comment: So you're saying that each code block has it's own intrinsic period? What if you want to include multiple blocks in a sentence, as in my last quoted example? What if you want to end the sentence with a question or exclamation mark? (Note that adding punctuation *in* the code block, as in your "I'm glad you're happy!" example, would be a big no no because then it will be interpreted as part of the code.)

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Yes, I think a code block has an intrinsic period. For commas or question marks, to keep to my theory, you would front-load all commentary... something like "Here are my three options... which is the best one?" followed by three code blocks.